# in LINQ to SQL how would i create an outer left join to the first element of the right table?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have two tables Orders and Products where Orders has a ProductID as a forgin key,
I would like to select all products, if a product has orders i would like to select the one with the highest distance field.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems a bit unclear. However, I am assuming that your orders table has a 'distance' column. You would like to select all products with the order that has the highest distance value.

```
var products = from p in db.Products
               select new
               {
                   ProductID = p.ProductID,
                   ProductName = p.ProductName,
                   HighestDistanceOrder = p.Orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.Distance).FirstOrDefault()
               };
```

If you wanted the value of highest distance and not the entire order, then

```
var products = from p in db.Products
               select new
               {
                   ProductID = p.ProductID,
                   ProductName = p.ProductName,
                   HighestDistance = p.Orders.Max(o => o.Distance)
               };
```

Hope that helps.

Matrich

Comment: wouldn't this solution actually cause mutiple sql quries?

Comment: For the first case i.e. returning the order with the highest distance value, it gets all the product details first and then creates a SELECT TOP (1) query for each of the products returned.

For case two which returns the highest distance value, it creates only one SQL query.

Comment: Is there any way to do a single query but still get the full row? (Max is for a single value)